# Render a polymorphic partial with optional belongs_to/nested inherited resources (Rails 3.1)

Tags: nested, ruby-on-rails-3.1, partial, inherited-resources

Trying to do something really simple--could someone please provide the correct incantation?

Basically we have `Biscuit` optionally nested in `User` so we'd like routes like:

```
/biscuits
/biscuits/1
/users/2/biscuits
/users/2/biscuits/3
```

etc.

We have views like `biscuits/index` which calls a partial `biscuits/_index` to render the list. I'd like to call this same partial from the user's profile view, `users/edit`, but I'm unclear on which resource_url helpers to use:

```
resources :users do
  resources :biscuits
end

class BiscuitsController < InheritedResources::Base
   belongs_to :user, optional: true
end
```

users/edit.html.haml:

```
= render 'biscuits/index', biscuits: @user.biscuits.all
```

biscuits/_index.html.haml:

```
  - biscuits.each do |biscuit|
    %tr
      %td= biscuit.title
      %td= link_to image_tag(biscuit.file_url(:thumb,:large)), resource_url(biscuit)
      %td
        = link_to 'Show', resource_url(biscuit)
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
      %td
        = link_to 'Edit', edit_resource_url(biscuit)
```

This partial works fine when called from the `BiscuitsController` at `/users/1/biscuits`, but it bombs with `NoMethodError in Users#edit undefined method 'user_url' for #<UsersController>` when called from the `UsersController` at `/users/1/edit` -- seems the `resource_url` refers to the user here not the biscuits collection.

How could I force the resource/collection to be any collection of resources, regardless of the current controller?

What's the better way to do this?

Also, say we override `UsersController#collection` and `#resource`, are these methods on the `UsersController` called if the route invokes the `BiscuitsController` via `/users/1/biscuits` ?  Or is only one `Controller` per request ever instantiated by Rails?

Comment: also note that `rake routes` shows the nested routes, `/user/:user_id/biscuits/:id` but does not show the optional non-nested `/biscuits/:id` -- is that expected behavior or does it indicate a problem?

Answer (score 1):

**regarding routes behavior** - as far as I know, if you want to use a route both nested and non-nested, you really should define it twice. i.e.

```
resources :users do
  resources :biscuits
end
resources :biscuits
```

that said, it seems to be considered better practice to nest resources only if there is no sense to access them without nesting. if you leave only the non-nested routes for biscuits it might solve your problem.

**regarding resource_url** - your references to resource_url and collection methods indicate you are using a plugin or gem, it's hard to know what's going wrong without knowing what plugin you are using especially since it seems to be the source of your problem.

substituting "resource_url" for a helper along the lines of

```
def nested_resource_path(*args)
  args = args.compact
  return args[0] if args.size == 1
  return args
end
```

called thus:

```
nested_resource_path(@user, biscuit) and
nested_resource_path(:edit, @user, biscuit)
```

where @user is nil when accessing BiscuitsController#index
 should work.

Answer (score 1):

chuck in a shallow route, that is:

```
resources :users, :shallow => true do
  resources :biscuits
end
```

then do rake routes and see if that does the trick